# How to use IHTMLDocument3::attachEvent

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, bho

I could not find any example using IHTMLDocument3::attachEvent in C++. The function described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is also different from what Visual Studio describes:

```
  MSDN: attachEvent(BSTR event, IDispatch *pDisp)
  VS: attachEvent(BSTR event, IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT_BOOL *pfResult)
```

Does anyone have an example in C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description is accurate: in C++ you have actually returned value `pfResult` as an `[out]` argument, and the method returns `HRESULT` to indicate success or failure (failure is translated to exception on script side).

`pDisp` needs to be implementation of `IDispatch` being able to handle `IDispatch::Invoke` with dispid of zero (`DISPID_VALUE`).